# Android Emulator Did not Launch

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to launch my andorid project on eclipse but i am taking this error:

Emulator unknown option: -dns-servers
         please use -help for a list of valid options

Can anybody help to fix it.

Comment: How are you launching the emulator?

Comment: right click run as android application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to **Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch**

In the `Default emulator options:` input`-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4` and click OK.